# How to access nextjs app from another computer on the same network

Tags: node.js, networking, next.js, localhost, port

This question seems easy, just go to the local ip of the computer that is running the server, add the port and you should see it. And I did that. These following addresses all work on the computer that is running the server.

```
http://localhost:3000/
http://127.0.0.1:3000/
http://192.168.1.201:3000/
```

However, the third option doesn't work at all on other computers on my local network. I can ping 192.168.1.201 and I get responses, but if I get nothing if I curl 192.168.1.201:3000

```
curl 192.168.1.201:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.201 port 3000 after 6 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Then, I thought my firewall must be blocking the connection from other computers, but nmap shows that the port is open:

```
nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-11-17 09:52 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000094s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 997 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3000/tcp open  ppp
// other ports

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

And now I have no idea why I can't access my server from the local network. I am open to any suggestions